# How to put a delay before showing: 'Attempting to reconnect to the server' in Blazor server side app?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor server side keeps a SignalR connection for real-time communication with its backend for the purpose of updating DOM changes. If I'm not mistaken, this websocket connections pings server at roughly every 2 seconds:

[image]

And As soon as the connection goes down, frontend side is presented with this message:
[image]

I looked into [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0#circuit-handler-options-for-blazor-server-apps) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options) and applied the following codes (to `Program.cs` file) for adding let say 10 seconds delay before the said pop up show up but to no avail:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddHubOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    });
```

or:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub(opts =>
    {
        opts.LongPolling.PollTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        opts.WebSockets.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        opts.TransportSendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    });
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

To further clarify the question, I'm not talking about customizing the pop up; I need a delay before the pop up (whatever shape and form) show up (when the connection goes down)

***ASP.NET Core 6.0***

Answer (score 0):

I add the codes in _Host.cshtml:

```
<div id="components-reconnect-modal" class="my-reconnect-modal components-reconnect-hide">
        <div class="show">
            <p>
                This is the message when attempting to connect to server
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="failed">
            <p>
                This is the custom message when failing
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="rejected">
            <p>
                This is the custom message when refused
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
    </app>

    
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

add the codes in site.css:

```
#components-reconnect-modal {
    transition-delay: 5s 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just tested your code. Doesn't work. As soon as the connection goes down, the pop up shows up.